# Django - How to do scoring in a quiz app with multiple attempts

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am making a quiz app in Django and struggling with the scoring.

This is my model setup:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=250)
    questions_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter the question text that you want displayed")

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField('Correct answer', default=False)

class QuizTaker(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    correct_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    attempt_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

In my html, the quiz is displayed as follows:

```
{% for q in question_list %}
  {{q}} <br>
  {% for choice in q.choice_set.all %}
      <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.answer }}">
      <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.answer }}</label><br>
  {% endfor %}
<a class='btn btn-warning save_ans' href="#">Save answer</a>
```

The answer to every question is handled via an ajax call and sent to the following view:

```
 ans_given = []
 def save_ans(request):
      ans = request.GET['ans']
      ans_given.append(ans)
      return HttpResponse(ans)
```

I've approached the scoring as follows:

```
ans_correct = []
answers = models.Choice.objects.filter(is_correct=True)

for i in answers:
    scoring['ans_correct'].append(i.answer)

def quiz_results(request, pk):
    score = 0
    quiz = models.Quiz.objects.get(song__pk=pk)
    count = quiz.questions_count

    questions = models.Question.objects.filter(quiz=quiz)
    for i in range(len(questions)):
        if ans_given[i] == ans_correct[i]:
            score +=1

    combined = list(zip(scoring['ans_correct'],scoring['ans_given']))
    return render(request, 'quizzes/quiz_song_result.html', {'score': score, 'combined': combined})
```

And this works fine, but only the first time. I want to allow the user to have multiple attempts at the quiz. After the first time, I get a `list index out of range` error, which of course makes sense, because it has kept the first `n` answers and added `n` more to the list, while the length of `ans_correct` of course doesn't change.

I've tried various ways to fix this, but to no avail. I've tried using `insert` instead of `append`, but can't get the indexing right. I've tried putting `ans_given.clear()` at the beginning of the function so that I start with a clean list every time, but it clears the list after every answer (not after the whole quiz).

I've also tried getting the answers like this:

```
for question in questions:
    answer = models.Choice.objects.values_list('answer', flat=True).get(is_correct=True, question=question)
    scoring['ans_correct'].append(answer)
```

And then doing the scoring in a similar way. In this case, the lists are at least of equal length, but the scoring still doesn't work and it messes up my template.

I'm pretty sure there's a simple solution to this and I'm just not seeing this. Or that there is a much better way to do what I want to do... so if anyone can help me, I'd be very grateful!

**Edit:**
I've managed to solve my problem as follows (*but I'm still keen for suggestions of how to approach this differently, even if it means redesigning a lot of it*).

```
ans_user = ans_given[len(ans_given)-len(questions):]
ans_corr = ans_correct[len(ans_given)-len(questions):]

for i in range(len(questions)):
    if ans_user[i] == ans_corr[i]:
        score +=1
```

Comment: Aren't you storing the answer somehwere? How do you pass ans_given value to `quiz_results`?

Comment: I'm just appending it to the `ans_given` list. Each answer is sent via an ajax request to the `save_ans` view. @ruddra